# ImportError: No module named 'nilearn'

Tags: python, nibabel, nilearn

I'm trying to plot `.nii` data using `nibabel` and `nilearn`. I'm using python 3.5 and installed both packages successfully. But, when I'm trying to import the module, it's returning -

> ImportError: No module named 'nilearn'.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably installing packages into a different Python installation than you're running your code in. Try the following commands:

```
# Use the pip for the first python on the path.
sudo python3 -m pip install <modules>
python3 <script>
```

That'll probably be enough to get this script running. However, as you continue to develop more applications, installing and upgrading libraries at the root level will mean break your applications. Look into Virtual Environments to give each application its own copy of Python and libraries. I also highly recommend looking into [Anaconda Python](https://www.anaconda.com/what-is-anaconda/) and its environment creator `conda` to do most of this for you.

Comment: Should I use a virtual environment then ?

Comment: I use virtual environment for other development. As this is just an academic task, thought it won't be necessary. But, that solved the problem. Don't know what was the problem but using virtual environment fixed it.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar You should create an answer to this question with the steps you used to fix it. Could help others :)

Comment: Already accepted your answer. 

Created a virtual environment and installed packages, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure about spelling of the module, then you should check whether you installed the module where python program checks.
So try:

```
import sys
for i in sys.path:print(i)
```

if the path to the module is not in it,add the path in by

```
sys.path.append('path to your module')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check and see if pip is installing the modules to the right place you can run:

```
which pip3
which python3
```

A virtualenv would probably fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the actual command to use with pip:

```
pip install -U --user nilearn
```